# NameError python api "vishnubob/kinet"

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am trying to run and learn all about the [vishnubob/kinet api](https://github.com/vishnubob/kinet).

After I download it I try to run the example script (also after fixing a couple syntax errors) I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 31, in <module>
    pds = PowerSupply("192.168.1.121")
NameError: name 'PowerSupply' is not defined
```

I have no clue why this is happening, as the imports look good (to me at least).

If someone knows why or can point me to the right direction then I would be grateful.

Comment: This thing was never updated for Python 3.

Comment: Please, no screenshots! Instead copy the error verbatim into the question - I did that for you because I was curious to see how badly broken that library would have been in Python 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clue here is "fixing syntax errors". That code has been written for Python 2, and it uses a thing called *implicit relative import* which was removed in Python 3. Namely the line in `kinet/__init__.py`

```
from kinet import *
```

is trying to import from the *top-level package* in Python 3, when Python 2 defaulted to importing from a local module first (`kinet/kinet.py`). The fix is to change this to

```
from .kinet import *
```

However this leads down the rabbit hole, as `kinet.py` has more syntax errors, after which it just fails spectacularly with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 31, in <module>
    pds = PowerSupply("192.168.1.121")
  File "./kinet/kinet.py", line 227, in __init__
    self.header = Header()
  File "./kinet/kinet.py", line 22, in __init__
    self._struct = struct.Struct(self.struct_format)
  File "./kinet/kinet.py", line 61, in __setattr__
    if key not in self.Keys:
  File "./kinet/kinet.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    if key not in self.Keys:
  File "./kinet/kinet.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    if key not in self.Keys:
  File "./kinet/kinet.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    if key not in self.Keys:
  [Previous line repeated 325 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

It is a bad piece of code written using all the syntax that was deprecated already in Python 2.6. I'd look for a Python 3 rewrite instead of trying to fix that.

Comment: unfortunately that dosnt exist, but thank you for your answer!! really helpful and a clear explanation